# Import powershell module fails

Tags: powershell, import, module

Can somebody explain what did I miss?

I'm trying to import `NTFSSecurity` PowerShell module.
The folder is extracted at `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`, and I've also changed the execution policy.

I'm still receiving the following error:
My system is running on the Windows 2008R2 operating system with PowerShell 2.0 installed

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

PS C:\Users\admin> get-module -ListAvailable -all

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Binary     PrivilegeControl          {}
Binary     ProcessPrivileges         {}
Binary     Security2                 {}
Manifest   ADRMS                     {}
Manifest   AppLocker                 {}
Manifest   BestPractices             {}
Binary     Microsoft.BestPractice... {}
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Binary     Microsoft.BackgroundIn... {}
Binary     NTFSSecurity              {}
Manifest   NTFSSecurity              {}
Binary     PrivilegeControl          {}
Binary     ProcessPrivileges         {}
Binary     Security2                 {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}
Script     PSDiagnostics             {}
Manifest   ServerManager             {}
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}

PS C:\Users\admin> import-module NTFSSecurity
Import-Module : The specified module 'NTFSSecurity' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
 directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ import-module <<<<  NTFSSecurity
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (NTFSSecurity:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your shell as administrator(elevated prompt) and unblock all the files in *NTFSSecurity* folder.

Comment: Tried unblocking the files. PS is running in elevated mode. Same red error: File list of NTFSSEcurity folder: NTFSSecurity-Help.xml
NTFSSecurity.dll
NTFSSecurity.format.ps1xml
NTFSSecurity.Init.ps1
NTFSSecurity.pdb
NTFSSecurity.psd1
NTFSSecurity.types.ps1xml
PrivilegeControl.dll
PrivilegeControl.pdb
ProcessPrivileges.dll
ProcessPrivileges.pdb
Security2.dll
Security2.pdb

Comment: Is this a 64bit box? If so, are you running 64bit powershell?

Comment: Thanks. It was blocked files.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was seeing this errors only during the azure devops pipeline deployment and so, I tried uninstall and re-install az modules and removed azurerm but nothing worked till I installed powershell 7.4.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).